# Comment traduire les groupes prépositionnels au singulier de l'anglais au français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs

### Contexte

Nous avons un programme qui s'appelle, en anglais, « Student Ambassador Program ». J'ai demandé à ma supérieure anglophone si le terme anglais correct n'était pas « Student Ambassador**s** Program » (au pluriel). Au départ, je trouvais que la deuxième formulation était mieux, mais selon elle, c'est la première qui est correcte. L'explication, c'est que dans la deuxième, l'emphase est sur les ambassadeurs, alors que dans le premier, l'emphase est sur le programme qui, si on peut dire, « forme » des ambassadeurs (donc singulier et non pas pluriel).

Ceci m'a amené à nouveau à une interrogation lors de la traduction du terme en français. Encore une fois j'avais la même tendance à vouloir pluraliser le terme, soit « Programme d'ambassadeurs étudiants » plutôt que sa forme au singulier « Programme d'ambassadeur étudiant ». Mais encore une fois, j'ai l'impression que la même nuance s'applique, c'est-à-dire soit l'emphase est sur les ambassadeurs, soit elle est sur le programme. Puisque nous traduisons de la forme-mère qui est de l'anglais, ne doit-on pas également calquer cette emphase ?

En outre, est-il grammaticalement incorrect de qualifier un programme au singulier ? Certaines personnes semblent suggérer que « Programme d'ambassadeur étudiant » sonne bizarre puisque cela indiquerait que le programme ne contiendrait qu'un seul ambassadeur. Est-ce vrai ?

Voici un autre exemple (je crois) ; en anglais, l'on dira, « an apple factory » et non pas « an apples factory » (au pluriel), alors qu'en français, on dira, « une usine à pommes », et non pas « une usine à pomme ». N'est-ce pas ?

#### Edit

Pour situer le terme dans son contexte (en réponse au commentaire ci-dessous), le terme *Student Ambassador Program*  est le nom du programme. Dans une phrase décrivant sa fonction, cela pourrait se lire ainsi : « The *Student Ambassador Program* is a program for students by students. It aims to form student leaders in student communities. »

Ou encore en français : « Le programme d'ambassadeur étudiant est un programme destiné aux étudiants, par les étudiants. Il vise à former des leaders étudiants dans les communautés étudiantes. »

### Question

En d'autres termes, quelle est la règle générale de traduction de ce type de situation ? Et quel est le bon terme que j'aurais pu indiquer dans un moteur de recherche pour trouver réponse à cette question (e.g., groupe prépositionnel,
complément du nom, adjectif relationnel—mais ce ne sont peut-être pas les bons termes) ?

Comment: Ce serait une excellente idée de situer ce nom composé en donnant sa définition dans votre question, comme par exemple "A Campus Ambassador program is the means for a company to maintain its brand presence among college/university students. In a campus ambassador program, companies hire and appoint ambassadors in colleges, and these campus ambassadors essentially represent the company in their campuses.". Sans faire cela on ne sait pas quoi modifie quoi.

Comment: Oui, bonne idée, quelque chose du genre? « The _Student Ambassador Program_ is a program for students by students that aims to form student leaders and ambassadors in their student communities. » J'ai édité ma question en ce sens.

Comment: Pas sûr d'avoir compris. Un *student leader and ambassador*, c'est le représentant d'un groupe d'étudiants vis a vis d'un autre groupe d'étudiants du même campus ?

Comment: @jlliagre, vous avez raison ce n'est pas très clair en ce moment. Je vais simplifier la description sans modifier la nature du problème.

Comment: @LPH C'est le programme qui vise, pas les étudiants qui visent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si j'ai bien compris de quoi il s'agit, ce sont en premier lieu des étudiants et ils ont un rôle d'ambassadeur de leur école / filière. La forme la plus idiomatique est alors :

> **Programme d'**[**étudiants-ambassadeurs**](https://www.iledefrance.fr/trophees-des-etudiants-ambassadeurs-de-lile-de-france-2019-2020)

ou

> [**Programme d'étudiants ambassadeurs**](https://www.universite-paris-saclay.fr/formation/orientation-et-insertion-professionnelle/programme-detudiants-ambassadeurs)

qui donne au singulier **étudiant-ambassadeur** ou **étudiant ambassadeur**.

La forme ***ambassadeurs étudiants*** ne convient pas car elle désignerait des ambassadeurs (plutôt des vrais, des diplomates) qui retourneraient à leurs études, ou du moins qui suivraient une formation donnée.

---

PS: En français on ne dit ni « une usine à pomme », ni vraiment « une usine à pommes » sauf pour plaisanter puisque les pommes ne se fabriquent pas dans des usines...

On peut dire « un verger » pour parler du vrai lieu de fabrication ou « une usine de conditionnement de pommes » pour parler du lieu de tri, calibrage, emballage et stockage des pommes.

Comment: Vous avez compris précisément. J'allais justement vous demander quelle était la différence entre étudiant-ambassadeur et ambassadeur-étudiant. En anglais la différence en est une d'emphase : Student Ambassadors met l'emphase principale sur leur statut d'ambassadeur, alors que Ambassador Students met l'emphase sur leur statut d'étudiant. Puisque normalement, de l'anglais au français, on renverse l'ordre des mots, je croyais approprié d'ici d'inverser étudiant et ambassadeur pour en conserver le sens original. Ce qui amène la question à savoir : la même nuance d'emphase joue-t-elle en français?

Comment: Je crois bien que oui selon votre exemple (que ce serait de vrais ambassadeurs de pays par exemple). Mais pourquoi cette interprétation n'est-elle pas présente en anglais dans la formulation commune? Vous amenez également un autre point, avec la réponse de LPH, qui suggérait que la formulation « d'ambassadeurs » est incorrecte, donc j'avais compris qu'il serait plus juste de dire « Programme _des_ ambassadeurs étudiants ». Mais cela ne semble pas être tout à fait exact au final vu les exemples que vous fournissez.

Comment: PS : Effectivement, une usine à pommes n'a pas vraiment de sens hehe. J'aurais peut-être dû dire « usine à bonbons » ou encore « usine à pommes de tire » par exemple.

Comment: Oui, on inverse en général l'ordre des mots quand on passe de l'anglais au français et c'est aussi valable pour les mots composés de deux substantifs comme par exemple homme-grenouille (*frogman*), poisson-chat (*catfish*), oiseau-mouche (*hummingbird*), wagon-restaurant (*dining car*). Peut-être que dans ce cas précis, le français accepte mal qu'ambassadeur puisse être la fonction principale des personnes en question et étudiant un qualificatif secondaire.

Answer (score -1):

Selon ce [modèle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve+professeur%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ves+professeurs%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ves+professeur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve%20professeur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ves%20professeurs%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve%20professeur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ves%20professeurs%3B%2Cc0) il faudrait que le pluriel de "ambassadeur étudiant" (traduction de "student ambassador") soit "**ambassadeur*s* étudiant*s***".

Tout d'abord, la préposition ne convient pas: le programme est en vue de former des ambassadeurs, et "de" est très imprécis. La meilleure façon de traduire consiste à ajouter un terme, « formation ». Cela donne donc « **Programme de formation d'ambassadeurs étudiants** ».

S'il n'y avait pas déjà le mot « étudiant » dans le composé, la préposition « pour » serait utilisable. Par exemple «  programme pour élèves professeurs » est une construction qui convient. Cependant, « programme pour élèves ambassadeur étudiants » n'est pas une construction qui soit immédiatement claire. Néanmoins, la construction avec « pour » n'est ni aussi formelle, ni aussi claire, ni aussi utilisée. Elle sera utilisé dans la conversation courante.

En français on ne dit pas « un programme d'ingénieur »,  « un programme d'infirmières », « un programme de techniciens », etc. dans le sens que le programme serait dédié à former les gens aux métiers indiqués ; on dit couramment  une école d'ingénieurs »,  « une école  d'infirmières », « une école de techniciens », etc. ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+%C3%A9cole+d%27ing%C3%A9nieurs%2Cune+%C3%A9cole+d%27infirmi%C3%A8res%2Cune+%C3%A9cole+de+techniciens&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20d%27%20ing%C3%A9nieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20d%27%20infirmi%C3%A8res%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20de%20techniciens%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20d%27%20ing%C3%A9nieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20d%27%20infirmi%C3%A8res%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20%C3%A9cole%20de%20techniciens%3B%2Cc0)) Il y a apparemment quelque chose d'inconsistant, mais c'est l'usage.
Si on dit par exemple « un programme d'ingénieur », cela signifie plutôt « un programme conçu par des ingénieurs ».

Non, en français le pluriel est nécessaire dans les expressions  « programme de formation de < nom >" le nom est au pluriel ; cependant, c'est le singulier qui est utilisé dans « une/sa/la/cette… formation de < nom >".

Oui, la seule possibilité est « une usine à pommes ».

On ne trouve pas « [student ambassadors program](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=student+ambassadors+program%2Cstudent+ambassador+program&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstudent%20ambassador%20program%3B%2Cc0) » en anglais ; il n'y a donc pas d'opposition de terme en tant qu'opposition défini par l'orthographe. De toute façon, il n'existe pas de forme alternative en français  pour marquer de l'emphase. Je n'en suis pas sûr, mais votre supérieur hiérarchique a peut-être voulu dire autre chose ; je ne vois pas ce que cette emphase signifie.

La règle générale a été énoncée au moyen d'un exemple, l'exemple que vous avez choisi (ambassadeur étudiant). Les termes suggérés ne donneraient pas de réponse sur cette question. Je ne vois pas quel terme serait une vrai solution.

Comment: Tout d'abord, vous clarifiez (grâce à l'outil de Google notamment) qu'en anglais, il semble n'y avoir qu'une seule véritable option, soit la forme au singulier, mais qu'en français aussi il n'y a qu'une seule option, soit la forme au pluriel.

Il est intéressant cependant de noter qu'avec ambassadors program (sans student), [les deux variations apparaissent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ambassadors+program%2Cambassador+program&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), bien que la version plurielle est moins courante donc probablement non-recommandée. Super.

Comment: Nous n'avons pas beaucoup de marge de manoeuvre concernant la longueur de la traduction (cela doit être aussi court qu'en anglais). Mais vous me faites réaliser qu'il serait peut-être plus correct de dire _Programme **des** ambassadeurs étudiants_ plutôt que _Programme d'ambassadeurs étudiants_, bien vue.

Enfin il est vrai que j'ai utilisé le terme formation, mais il serait aussi correct de dire que c'est le programme _des_ ambassadeurs (prêt du sens « appartient aux ambassadeurs, leur programme » et donc cette dernière formulation aurait du sens sans mentionner la formation). Merci!

Comment: @RemPsyc 1/  Les deux variations ne sont pas les mêmes : si vous examinez les exemples, vous trouvez que « ambassadors » in'est pas modifié et que c'est plutôt  « ambassadors sth » qui est modifié ; donc je ne sais pas si c'est valide. 2/ Si vous examinez les livres pour « programme de …» vous ne trouverez pas de forme analogue à « programme d'ambassadeurs étudiants » ; je conçois que l'on puisse dire que c'est leur programme mais on peut dire la même chose des personnes qui ont conçu ce programme et aussi de celles qui l'exécutent ; attendez d'autres réponses, je pourrais avoir tort. (1/2)

Comment: @RemPsyc Voilà le lien pour « programme de  …»: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programme%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: Vous apportez de bon points. Dans le même sens, il est intéressant de noter les différentes traductions sur [linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=ambassador+program) (bien que cela n'ait peut-être pas grande valeur ou autorité). Nous voyons la forme la plus simple Programme ambassadeur (pas de déterminants, singulier), Programme ambassadeurs (pas de déterminants, pluriel), Programme d'ambassadeurs (avec déterminant, pluriel), Programme des Ambassadeurs (forme indiquée plus tôt). Un autre exemple proche du mon cas : Programme des employés ambassadeurs.

Comment: @RemPsyc Je n'ai pas pu vérifier toutes les sources car le chargement n'est pas fait mais pour celles qui le sont (6 ou 7 accédées) elles sont toutes canadiennes et les canadiens sont connus pour leur accumulation d'anglicismes dans le français canadien (Le français canadien n'est pas le français).

Comment: @LPH *Le français canadien n'est pas le français.* ROTFL Comment peut tu écrire de telles énormités (avec une faute de français en plus)? Il est vrai que tu es coutumier du fait...  Il ne viendrait à personne l'idée de dire que l'anglais parlé aux États-Unis n'est pas de l'anglais. C'est pareil pour le français utilisé au Canada qui est bien sûr du français. Tu seras d'ailleurs probablement surpris d'apprendre que les Canadiens francophones reprochent au français de France une accumulation d'anglicismes. Ce ne sont simplement pas les mêmes.

Comment: @jlliagre Même la prononciation peut être très différente; à plusieurs reprise j'ai écouté des canadiens français et il était impossible de savoir ce qu'ils disaient .  Il est évident que toutes les sources sont canadiennes ; ça ne signifie rien  ?

Comment: @LPH Un accent, tout le monde en a, sauf les muets, cela va de soi !